# Using queryParam linked or unlinked with WebTarget DELETE produces different results

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-client

I have a basic `javax.ws.rs` REST API class:

```
@Path("/")
public class DeleteApi {
    @DELETE
    public void testDelete(@DefaultValue("false") @QueryParam("id") boolean id) {
        logger.info("id [{}]", id);
    }
}
```

I'm using a `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` within a test to test this DELETE method:

```
@Test
public void testCallDelete() {
    // Not linked version
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8080/fscrawler/");
    target.queryParam("id", true);
    target.request().delete();

    // Linked version
    client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8080/fscrawler/")
            .queryParam("id", true)
            .request()
            .delete();
}
```

It produces:

```
23:37:14,870 INFO  [f.p.e.c.f.r.RestApi] id [false]
23:37:14,910 INFO  [f.p.e.c.f.r.RestApi] id [true]
```

In case it's helpful here is my main dependencies in my `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I know I'm doing something probably stupid but still can see what is my error here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
target.queryParam("id", true);
```

Doesn't modify `target`, it just returns a *new* WebTarget with the queryparam set

You could do

```
target = target.queryParam("id", true);
```

but your second test is the correct way